# How to efficiently fetch one column using CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a Table with 50,000 records (table has 8 columns). I need to display only 1st column on the Table. I need an array which contains all data from Table only from 1st column. How to use NSFetchRequest to get all record from 1st column of the Table using Core Data?

Comment: do you need rows sorted or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Currently order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use setPropertiesToFetch: method like

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"<#Attribute name#>"]];
```

e.g.,

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ColName", nil]];
```

Refer [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html)